# Fragment Management and Navigation delivery App

Tags: python

I am trying to build a delivery app. I have a list of products to choose from. After the user selects a product then he is lead to a series of stages to define extras and options of a certain product.

Comment: I see no question here. No code, no description of your design, no problem you're currently facing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any code? I don't know how you want it, though if you have code I could help.
Try this start, though.

`products = [] product = input("Product: ") try: print("Products: %s"%products[product]) except: print("Product (s) not found.") products = input("")`